# addmob test ads not displaying anymore

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, admob

I made a game with unity for android and I'm having problems wirh admob.When I first set the AdMob It was working fine.But now, it's not showing banner and when I request interstitial, the app directly closes.

When I run the code in Unity, it works fine. I can see the following in the console:

Created DummyClient
Dummy CreateBannerView
Dummy LoadAd

When I compile the code for android, I can't get past the initializing.

MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

using UnityEngine.UI;

public class reklamlar : MonoBehaviour
{

private BannerView bannerView;

string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";

void Start()
{

MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });

this.RequestBanner();

ShowBannerAd();
}

public void RequestBanner()

{
this.bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
Debug.Log("banner Request");

}

public void ShowBannerAd()
{

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
this.bannerView.LoadAd(request);
Debug.Log("banner Show");

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine works in these steps:

Step 1 - Setting JAVA_HOME in windows:
         https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Step 2 - Switch your project to Android

Step 3 - Add AdMob appid to your project

Assets>Google Mobile Ads>Settings>

(then enable the google admob and enter appid you can see in inspector window)

Step 4 - Then Force Resolve the project
Assets>Play Services Resolver>Android Resolver>Force Resolve

Step 5 - Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class AdScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    string AppId = "(your App ID)";
    string InterstitialAdID = "(test adid or real adid)";
    string BannerAdId = "(test adid or real adid)";

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private BannerView bannerView;
    void Start()
    {

        MobileAds.Initialize(AppId);

        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            RequestBannerAd();
            RequestInterstitial();
        }
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(InterstitialAdID);

        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        this.interstitial.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        this.interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
        // Called when an ad is shown.
        this.interstitial.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
        // Called when the ad is closed.
        this.interstitial.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
        // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
        this.interstitial.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }

    private void RequestBannerAd()
    {
        this.bannerView = new BannerView(BannerAdId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
        // Create an empty ad request.

        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        this.bannerView.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleOnAdLoaded;
        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        this.bannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
        // Called when an ad is clicked.
        this.bannerView.OnAdOpening += this.HandleOnAdOpened;
        // Called when the user returned from the app after an ad click.
        this.bannerView.OnAdClosed += this.HandleOnAdClosed;
        // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
        this.bannerView.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;


    }



    public void ShowinterstitialAds()
    {
        if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.interstitial.Show();
        }
    }

    public void ShowbannerViewAds()
    {
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

         Load the banner with the request.
        this.bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }


    #region interstitial and banned handler

    public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: "
                            + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");
    }

    public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");
        RequestInterstitial();
    }

    public void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeavingApplication event received");
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Hope this will work ;)